# how to get get array value in url

Tags: javascript

In PHP I am doing the below which works.

```
$urlParam = $_GET['abc_filter']['1e7678d987'];
```

But I need to do this in javascript as well.

This works for normal parameters:

```
    function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}

var someVal = getQueryVariable("someVal");
```

But I am not sure what I would put in place 'someVal' inside  `getQueryVariable("someVal");`

Comment: You can check URLSearchParams (mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)
If it feets, check can I use https://caniuse.com/ to check if is ok
If you need more help, please include url and expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `URL` method for parse url

```js
const url = new URL('https://stackoverflow.com/?a=test');
console.log(url.searchParams.get('a'));
//or if you iterate params
url.searchParams.forEach((v,k)=>{
  console.log(`${k}=>${v}`);
});
```

Comment: This is your application requirements, but when you are not certain about query string then you can use `forEach` to extract all data